# Server-side routing with an AngularJS SPA

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, iis, routes

I'm using ASP.NET MVC, IIS 8 and I'm using AngularJS to create a SPA. I only have this routing rule defined in my MVC application, that directs to `Index` method in `Home` controller, where my SPA lives:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultHome",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Now I have bunch of client-side SPA routes and I want all of them to available without the hashbang prefix `#/`. html5Mode works perfectly - but only **when the app has been loaded**. If I copy the URL, close the window, open the window and paste it in, I get an IIS 404 error. That makes sense because the routing is done on the server.

So sharing the URL doesn't work, which I would like to be able to do. So the routing has also to be done server-side, but everytime I change the route (add client side route), I don't want to have to create a server side routing rule.

Can this be done in general? Like something that URL rewrites `/*` to `#/*` without redirecting the user? With an exception for `/Static`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the url to `"{*catchall}"`. Like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultHome",
    url: "{*catchall}",
    defaults: new { controller ="Home", action= "Index" }
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. If I create a client side route `http://server/#/some/cool/route` I want it to be available through `http://server/some/cool/route`. Will this make it so?

Comment: Some weird happened when I tried this. The view is loaded twice, once as the master page in MVC and once in UI-Router's `<ui-view>`